# Images disappear in Django app when deployed to Heroku

Tags: django, heroku

l have deployed my app to Heroku but some images are no longer being loaded.

For example, people's profile pics are not showing up, but if that person re-uploads one it will be visible. However, when they log out/in again, the picture is no longer there.

What would cause this type of behavior and how can I fix it? Locally everything works fine.

Comment: check the path of the images, see if their paths are set to local ones

Comment: Well it's using the MEDIA_ROOT directory and MEDIA_URL to access. Isn't it strange that they work properly for 1-2 hours or so and then suddenly they disappear? That makes me wonder if there's something refreshing on Heroku and deleting them?

Comment: Is there a way for me to check the path to which the photo is being saved by Heroku?

Comment: same thing happening with my application,

Answer (score 2):

I found this information on http://www.gettingstartedwithdjango.com/introduction-and-launch.html#what-heroku-does-every-time-you-push-to-them-is

What Heroku does every time you push to them is:

- Creates a new app space with its own virtual machine, virtual environment, and packages installed through pip.
- Swaps the subdomain over to the new location.
- Deletes the old app space.

What this means is that anything added to the app that is not in Git, won’t last between pushes. Even more, this exact same process happens once every 24 hours anyway, so uploaded files have to go somewhere other than Heroku.

You might look into this as a possible source of your issue.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an answer from the [pythonanywhere](https://www.pythonanywhere.com) blog which may answer your question. 
Basically, when going into production, setting (in settings.py) `DEBUG = False` raises a security lock on the file tampering with the image urls.

So basically a file path change is in order for the `MEDIA_ROOT` from development to production.
More information given on the blog [here](https://www.pythonanywhere.com/forums/topic/1674/#id_post_47183).

Hope this helps!